# DiveIntoPython like for Java?

Tags: java

Any Java tutorial that resembles Mark Pilgrim's approach for [DiveIntoPython](http://www.diveintopython.net/)?

Comment: That, I'd like to know as well :D

Comment: I thought Scott Pilgrim was the cartoon character...

Comment: Is it a beginner's book?

Answer (score 4):

What about the official Java Tutorial? I found it pretty helpful to get started with the language.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't read Dive Into Python but I do know that Bruce Eckels Thinking In Java is an excellent book and well worth a look.

Be warned though - it's monster size and not easy to carry around!

Comment: you should take a look at Mark Pilgrim's book. It's a free online book that teaches Python with a simple but effective practical way.

Comment: I am downloading it as I type.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything like *Dive into Python* in the Java world. The Java language doesn't lend itself to the model of 'Check out what we can do with these 15 lines of code!'

Best approach would be to dive in yourself, pick a project, and use the tutorial and the docs. Many people will recommend Eckel's *Thinking in Java* but know that it is the polar opposite of *Dive into Python* -- it is slow, methodical, and thorough.